# What are some other generic http clients available?

Tags: http

In addition to [jakarta commons http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), what are some other generic http clients? Can you point to what were your learnings experiences with it?

Answer (score 2):

[LWP](http://gitorious.org/projects/libwww-perl) is the standard HTTP library for Perl. I haven't used it very much, but I do use its companion command-line utilities (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) a bit, and they have a useful set of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (a.k.a. libcurl).  libcurl has bindings for about 40 different programming languages.